# Read and write data to a central database between multiple devices

Tags: android, database

So, I'm working on an android app that will have to record data to a central database. Because there will be multiple users adding to the database from different devices, I think I'll need to host it somewhere accessible to each device. I'm new to this concept but if anyone could recommend a way for me to create and host a database where multiple devices can read/write to that would be great. Thanks!!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @AmirMohamamd how can I host a database where multiple people can read and write to it over different devices? Are there any free options?

Comment: You should look at Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 :
Read about Rest API and json

Step 2 :
Create sample API(you can use any back-end language you like, e.g php django ...) in your local host (dont need to buy host)

Step 3 :
Read about Retrofit library and communicate between API and your app